# Invalid XML error from OneNote API

Tags: xml, api, onenote

I am trying to create a table in a new page on OneNote via the COM API. It's coming back with invalid XML but I can't figure out why... I'd appreciate any expert help :)

I'm getting the following error:

**Exception from HRESULT: 0x80042001**

When running this code:

```
    static string CreatePage(string sectionId, string pageName)
    {
        // Create the new page
        string pageId;
        onenoteApp.CreateNewPage(sectionId, out pageId, NewPageStyle.npsBlankPageWithTitle);

        var doc = CreateTable();

        // Update the page
        onenoteApp.UpdatePageContent(doc.ToString());

        return pageId;
    }
```

The error lokup comes back with:

```
hrInvalidXML
0x80042001
The XML is invalid.
```

Both the XML examples below fail...

Here's some cut down XML I'm loading:

```
<Page>  <Outline>    <OEChildren>      <OE>                  <T><![CDATA[test 2-3 ]]></T>      </OE>    </OEChildren>  </Outline></Page>
```

Here's the main XML

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2010/onenote">
  <Outline>
    <OEChildren>
      <OE>
        <Table>
          <Columns>
            <Column />
            <Column />
            <Column />
          </Columns>
          <Row>
            <Cell>
              <OEChildren>
                <OE>
                  <T><![CDATA[test 1-1 ]]></T>
                </OE>
              </OEChildren>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
              <OEChildren>
                <OE>
                  <T><![CDATA[test 1-2 ]]></T>
                </OE>
              </OEChildren>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
              <OEChildren>
                <OE>
                  <T><![CDATA[test 1-3 ]]></T>
                </OE>
              </OEChildren>
            </Cell>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Cell>
              <OEChildren>
                <OE>
                  <T><![CDATA[test 2-1 ]]></T>
                </OE>
              </OEChildren>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
              <OEChildren>
                <OE>
                  <T><![CDATA[test 2-2 ]]></T>
                </OE>
              </OEChildren>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
              <OEChildren>
                <OE>
                  <T><![CDATA[test 2-3 ]]></T>
                </OE>
              </OEChildren>
            </Cell>
          </Row>
        </Table>
      </OE>
    </OEChildren>
  </Outline>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML has a few problems:

1. Your `Page` element doesn't have the `ID` attribute. Without it OneNote doesn't know which page you are trying to update. In general you should read the page first and modify the XML and then update it with the new XML. This will preserve anything you didn't intend to modify.
2. Your `Column` elements are missing the required `index` and `width` attributes, which is what makes your XML invalid (does not conform to the XSD schema). For creating tables, if you don't want to specify the column widths, you don't need to even provide `Columns` and `Column` elements. They will be created once the page is updated.

---

**Edit by Original Poster**

In case anyone is interested\has similar problems I changes the CreateTable function

```
static XDocument CreateTable(string PageID)
{
    var page = new XDocument(new XElement(ns + "Page",
       new XElement(ns + "Outline",
         new XElement(ns + "OEChildren",
           new XElement(ns + "OE",
             new XElement(ns + "Table",
                new XElement(ns + "Row",
                    new XElement(ns + "Cell",
                         new XElement(ns + "OEChildren",
                           new XElement(ns + "OE",
                             new XElement(ns + "T",
                               new XCData("test 1-1 "))))),
                    new XElement(ns + "Cell",
                         new XElement(ns + "OEChildren",
                           new XElement(ns + "OE",
                             new XElement(ns + "T",
                               new XCData("test 1-2 "))))),
                    new XElement(ns + "Cell",
                         new XElement(ns + "OEChildren",
                           new XElement(ns + "OE",
                             new XElement(ns + "T",
                               new XCData("test 1-3 ")))))),
                new XElement(ns + "Row",
                    new XElement(ns + "Cell",
                         new XElement(ns + "OEChildren",
                           new XElement(ns + "OE",
                             new XElement(ns + "T",
                               new XCData("test 2-1 "))))),
                    new XElement(ns + "Cell",
                         new XElement(ns + "OEChildren",
                           new XElement(ns + "OE",
                             new XElement(ns + "T",
                               new XCData("test 2-2 "))))),
                    new XElement(ns + "Cell",
                         new XElement(ns + "OEChildren",
                           new XElement(ns + "OE",
                             new XElement(ns + "T",
                               new XCData("test 2-3 "))))))))))));

    page.Root.SetAttributeValue("ID", PageID);

    return page;
}
```

and called it with this:

```
var doc = CreateTable(pageId);
```