# Programmatically adding/displaying/inserting images to OneNote 2013

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble adding an image to a page in OneNote 2013. I can create sections, notebooks and pages with content, but I'm having trouble adding an image to the page.

I call UpdatePageContent and pass in the xml but I get an invalid XML message (hresult 0x80042001) back. Any assistance appreciated. Here is the complete code that I use to create an XML that I'm trying to update the page with:

```
Sub CreateNewPage(ByVal pageName As String)
    Dim OneNote As Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application
    OneNote = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application

    ' Get all of the Notebook nodes. 
    Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    nodes = GetFirstOneNoteNotebookNodes(oneNote)
    If Not nodes Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the first OneNote Notebook in the XML document. 
        Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
        node = nodes(0)
        Dim noteBookName As String = ""
        noteBookName = node.attributes.getNamedItem("name").text

        ' Get the ID for the Notebook so the code can retrieve 
        ' the list of sections. 
        Dim notebookID As String
        notebookID = node.attributes.getNamedItem("ID").text

        ' Load the XML for the Sections for the Notebook requested. 
        Dim sectionsXml As String = ""
        oneNote.GetHierarchy(notebookID, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsSections, sectionsXml)

        Dim secDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
        secDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

        If secDoc.loadXML(sectionsXml) Then
            ' select the Section nodes 
            Dim secNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
            secNodes = secDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("//one:Section[@name='Balaji1']")

            If Not secNodes Is Nothing Then
                ' Get the first section. 
                Dim secNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                secNode = secNodes(0)

                Dim sectionName As String = ""
                sectionName = secNode.attributes.getNamedItem("name").text
                Dim sectionID As String
                sectionID = secNode.attributes.getNamedItem("ID").text

                Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
                doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

                'oneNote.GetHierarchy()
                Dim sectionXML As String = ""
                Dim newPageID As String = ""
                sectionXML = ""
                oneNote.GetHierarchy("", Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsPages, sectionXML)
                newPageID = GetPageIDByPageName(pageName, sectionXML)

                ' Create a new blank Page in the first Section 
                ' using the default format. 
                If Len(newPageID) = 0 Then
                    oneNote.CreateNewPage(sectionID, newPageID, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.NewPageStyle.npsDefault)
                End If
                ' Get the contents of the page. 
                Dim outXML As String = ""
                oneNote.GetPageContent(newPageID, outXML, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.PageInfo.piAll)


                ' Load Page's XML into a MSXML2.DOMDocument object. 
                If doc.loadXML(outXML) Then
                    ' Get Page Node. 
                    Dim pageNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                    pageNode = doc.selectSingleNode("//one:Page")

                    ' Find the Title element. 
                    Dim titleNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                    titleNode = doc.selectSingleNode("//one:Page/one:Title/one:OE/one:T")

                    ' Get the CDataSection where OneNote store's the Title's text. 
                    Dim cdataChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                    cdataChild = titleNode.selectSingleNode("text()")

                    'change the title will change the pageName
                    ' Change the title in the local XML copy. 
                    cdataChild.text = pageName
                    ' Write the update to OneNote. 
                    oneNote.UpdatePageContent(doc.xml)

                    Dim newElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
                    Dim newNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

                    ' Create Outline node. 
                    newElement = doc.createElement("one:Outline")
                    newNode = pageNode.appendChild(newElement)
                    ' Create OEChildren. 
                    newElement = doc.createElement("one:OEChildren")
                    newNode = newNode.appendChild(newElement)
                    ' Create OE. 
                    newElement = doc.createElement("one:OE")
                    newNode = newNode.appendChild(newElement)
                    ' Create TE. 
                    newElement = doc.createElement("one:T")
                    newNode = newNode.appendChild(newElement)

                    newElement = doc.createElement("one:Image")
                    newNode = newNode.appendChild(newElement)

                    ' Add the text for the Page's content. 
                    Dim cd As MSXML2.IXMLDOMCDATASection
                    cd = doc.createCDATASection("YOUR TEXT HERE")

                    newNode.appendChild(cd)

                    ' Update OneNote with the new content. 
                    oneNote.UpdatePageContent(doc.xml)

                    ' Print out information about the update. 
                    MsgBox("A new page was created in Section '" & sectionName & "' in Notebook '" & noteBookName & "'.")

                    Debug.Print(doc.xml)
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("OneNote 2010 Section nodes not found.")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("OneNote 2010 Section XML Data failed to load.")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("OneNote 2010 XML Data failed to load.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it VB.Net or VBA. They are two distinct languages.

Comment: Most likely your XML is just not formatted correctly. Here is a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277771/invalid-xml-error-from-onenote-api

Comment: It is VB.Net, I am totally stuck here and not able to proceed further on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!